# How to prevent empty area/space selection in Safari on double click?

Tags: html, css, safari

Text selection in Safari browser is strange. You can select not only text, but some "empty" spaces on double click. Here you are:

[image]

The selected area is nothing of td tag!

I need to prevent this behavior in my case and select only text or nothing.
Any ideas?

Very simple JSFiddle after a lot of investigation: https://jsfiddle.net/vadimcpp/u38y5fsh/5/

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="my-cell"><div>Cell 1</div></td>
    <td class="my-cell"><div>Cell 2</div></td>
    <td class="my-cell"><div>Cell 3</div></td>
    <td class="my-cell"><div>Cell 4</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.my-cell {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  height: 75px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.my-cell {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  height: 75px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Chrome/Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE10+ */
}

.selectable {
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  /* Chrome/Safari */
  -moz-user-select: text;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: text;
  /* IE10+ */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="my-cell">
      <div class="selectable">Cell 1</div>
    </td>
    <td class="my-cell">
      <div class="selectable">Cell 2</div>
    </td>
    <td class="my-cell">
      <div class="selectable">Cell 3</div>
    </td>
    <td class="my-cell">
      <div class="selectable">Cell 4</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```